# Upper bound for degree of polynomial according to factor and $\ell_1$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials

I have an integer polynomial $P = a_{d+2} X^{d+2} + a_{d+1} X^{d+1} + \dots + a_0 \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with the two following properties: $a_0\neq 0$ and $P(\varphi)=0$, where $\varphi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden mean. I would like to bound the degree of the polynomial according to its $\ell_1$-norm, i.e. $\Vert P \Vert_1 = \sum_i^{d+2} |a_i|$.

Because $\varphi$ is a zero of $P$, I know that $X^2 - X - 1$ divides $P$. In other words, there must be a $Q = b_{d} X^{d} + b_{d-1} X^{d-1} + \dots + b_0 \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with $b_0 \neq 0$ such that
\begin{equation}
P = (X^2 - X - 1)Q.
\end{equation}
In terms of the polynomial coefficients, we have the relation
\begin{equation}
a_i = b_{i-2} - b_{i-1} - b_{i},
\end{equation}
with the understanding that in this formula $b_{i>d} = b_{i<0} = 0$. Trivially if $d=2$ then $\Vert P \Vert_1 \geq 3$. Using triangle inequality, I checked that if  $d=3$ then $\Vert P \Vert_1 \geq 4$ and I know by another method that if $\Vert P \Vert_1 = 4$ then either $deg(P) = 3$ or $deg(P) = 4$.

Ideally, I am looking for an upper bound on $d$ in terms of $\Vert P \Vert_1$. But maybe it is more natural to go the other way around and find a lower bound for $\Vert P \Vert_1$ in terms of $d$. I have the intuition that both exist. The idea is that because of the recurrence relation, starting with a non-zero $b_0$, if you try to match the $b_{i<d}$'s to get small $a_i$, you get penalised at the end by a large $b_d = a_{d+2}$ coefficient. Unfortunately, trying to recurrently apply triangle inequalities did not get me anywhere.

I do not have an advanced mathematical background, so any suggestions of keywords or literature would already be welcomed.

Thank you in advance!

**edit** My initial guess is too naïve, as for $\Vert P \Vert_1=6$, $P=(X^2-X-1)(X^d+1)$ with $d>2$ is an admissible candidate with unbounded degree. This answers already my original question by the negative but I think my idea still holds if we restrict to $P = a_{d+2} X^{d+2} + a_{d+1} X^{d+1} + \dots + a_0 \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that there is no "nested polynomial" $R = a_{i} X^{i} + a_{i-1} X^{i-1} + \dots + a_{j} X^j \in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, with $d+2\geq i \geq j \geq 0$ such that $R(\varphi) = 0$. Maybe that is the ingredient I was missing in my first attempts to find an upper bound on $d$.

Comment: What shape of inequality are you trying to find? An upper bound for $d$ in terms of $||P||_1$? A lower bound for $d$ in terms of $||P||_1$? Or do you want a bound for $||P||_1$ in terms of $d$?

Comment: Ideally, I am looking for an upper bound on $d$ in terms of $\Vert P \Vert_1$. But maybe it is more natural to go the other way around and find a lower bound for $\Vert P \Vert_1$ in terms of $d$.  I have the intuition that both exist. I have edited the question as well. The lower bound for $d $ in terms of $\Vert P \Vert_1$ is not so interesting (because for $\Vert P \Vert_1 = 3 n$, $P = n(X^2-X-1)$ works).